# Does this allocation have any effects on speed?

Tags: c++, performance, draw

This non-member function `drawPoly()` draws an n-sided polygon in 3D space from a list of vertices.

This function typically gets called thousands of times during normal execution and speed is critical.

Ignoring the effects of the functions called within `drawPoly()`, does the allocation of the 25-element vertex array have any negative effects on speed?

```
void drawPoly(const meshx::Face& face, gen::Vector position,
    ALLEGRO_COLOR color, bool filled)
{
    ALLEGRO_VERTEX vertList[25];
    std::size_t k = 0;

    // ...For every vertex in the polygon...
    for(; k < face.getNumVerts(); ++k) {
        vertList[k].x = position.x + face.alVerts[k].x;
        vertList[k].y = position.y + face.alVerts[k].y;
        vertList[k].z = position.z + face.alVerts[k].z;
        vertList[k].u = 0;
        vertList[k].v = 0;
        vertList[k].color = color;
    }
    // Draw with ALLEGRO_VERTEXs and no textures.
    if(filled) {
        al_draw_prim(vertList, nullptr, nullptr,
            0, k, ALLEGRO_PRIM_TRIANGLE_LIST);
    } else {
        al_draw_prim(vertList, nullptr, nullptr,
            0, k, ALLEGRO_PRIM_LINE_LOOP);
    }
}
```

Comment: That literally translates to a single  `sub esp, N` instruction (or close enough, where N is the count of aligned bytes required for 25 structures) if the vertex type is POD (and it probably is). You know you could always ram this through asm-list generation and check for what is happening in optimized release builds.

Comment: `ALLEGRO_VERTEX vertList[25];` *"does the allocation of the 25-element vertex array have any negative effects on speed?"* - No. You are *declaring* an array with *automatic storage duration* on the function stack itself. The function stack will be provided with sufficient size to handle a 25-element array many times over. There is no call to a memory allocation function, it is simply a declaration. (which is probably one of the, if not the, most efficient way to get a 25-element array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to tell it for sure, is to measure. But what else could you use instead, to compare with? Allocating on the heap would be obviously slower. Using a global variable to hold the vertices could be an option - only for perf benchmarking.

Given that the stack allocation of trivially constructible objects is usually translates to a simple change of the stack pointer, the allocation itself probably wouldn't be a big deal. What could have an observable effect tough, is touching extra cache lines. The less cache lines the code writes, the better, from the performance perspective. Therefore, you can experiment with splitting `vertList[25]` into cache line sized arrays, and calling `al_draw_prim` multiple times. A benchmark would show if there's a difference.